# How to revert a merge commit using JGit/EGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I have come to know that JGit does not support `git revert -m 1 <SHA>` command. Is there any other way using JGit which can help me revert a merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JGit currently cannot revert merge commits (or more generally, commits with more than one parent). It will throw a `MultipleParentsNotAllowedException` if any of the `include`ed commits is a merge commit.

I don't know of a workaround other than adapting and modifying the `ResetCommand` source code or (even better) contributing a change to JGit.

If you search the `RevertCommand` source code for `MultipleParentsNotAllowedException` you are close to where the change would need to take place. A few lines below, the source parent is determined like this:

```java
RevCommit srcParent = srcCommit.getParent(0);
```

which would need to change to:

```java
RevCommit srcParent = srcCommit.getParent(mainlineIndex);
```

and of course a getter and setter for `mainlineIndex`.